# Function theory in javascript - what does this return

Tags: javascript

I’m still trying to get to grips with function definitions: am I correct in saying that this returns a type of undefined?

```
function foo() {
  return
  {
    car: 'Audi'
  };
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It returns `undefined`, because of Automatic Semicolon Insertion. This is one of the major ASI hazards. Having a line break after `return` makes it get treated as `return;`. So your code ends up being:

```
function foo() {
  return;         // <=== Function returns here
  {               // \
    car: 'Audi'   //  > This is a freestanding block with a labelled statement which is the expression 'Audi'
  };              // /
}
```

Remove the line break and it returns an object:

```
function foo() {
  return {
    car: 'Audi'
  };
}
```

This is one reason that putting the opening `{` on things is standard practice in JavaScript, even more so than other C-like languages.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript assumes `return` to be `return;`, if you want to return any value it should be in the same line as `return`.

If you are getting `undefined` when you execute this function `foo`, that's because the function is returning at `return` itself, to get the object as return value, modify your function to be

```
function foo() {
  return {
    car: 'Audi'
  };
}
```